# The operation cannot be started by an account that uses SQL Server Authentication. SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a remote access in SSMS, when I try to execute an SSIS package I get, the operation can not be started by an account that uses SQL Server Authentication

[image]

[image]

How to fixed it?

Note: I can not use Windows Authentication remotely.

Comment: On that session in SSMS, you will need to login using Windows Authentication. You can read more [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/execute-package-utility-dtexecui-ui-reference).

Comment: I can not use Windows Authentication remotely.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot use a SQL Account to run an SSIS package in the Integration Services Catalog. There is logic within the CLR methods that are used to run the SSIS packages that reject non-windows authentication (as you have discovered).

As a consultant, I ran into issues where I'd use my corporate laptop plugged into a client's network. In that case, my account sdc\billinkc would not exist in the client domain. Instead, their servers would expect client\bfellows credentials to be presented. The work around is to use [RunAs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525.aspx). Alternate [reference](http://ss64.com/nt/runas.html)

From my [answer on deploying ispac to foreign domain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14485620/181965)...

> I created a suite of batch files that launch every process I need. They take the form of

```
runas /netonly:client\bfellows "C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe"
```

> I have one for a command prompt (above), Visual Studio, SSMS, PowerShell, PowerShell ISE and some other specialty apps that need to work with their domain.
>
> Using the runas approach, I've been able to deploy packages using all of the above methods (as well as deploying directly from a Visual Studio instance being run with foreign credentials).

You'd want to use ssms.exe and the correct install path to launch management studio and then SSIS packages would run.

## Approach #2

If you don't have an account in the foreign domain and the only thing they are willing to do is create a sql login, then they will also need to

- Create a Credential
- Create a Proxy
- Create a SQL Agent job that uses the proxy to run the SSIS package
- Grant the sql login the rights to run the job

This will allow you to run an SSIS package in a manner that is allowed as well as present domain credentials to the required resources.

Comment: Can you elaborate on Approach#2.

Answer (score 1):

For future Googlers, adding a Windows Authentication login as sysadmin and turning on **"Impersonate Any Login"** on the SQL Auth login (also sysadmin) as described in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60850142/1703887) allowed us to use `"EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'server\winuser'"` and successfully execute the package via the SQL Auth account.

You just have to be sure you are connected to the SSISDB database when executing the commands.